# Too many arguments in use if and lookup functions

Tags: array, lookup

I am using an `IF` formula with `LOOKUP` in order to evaluate and return a value in a table.  For example, to return a value in a salary matrix,

`=IF(K5>10,G5+SMI!$G$25,IF(I5=1,LOOKUP(K5,SMI!$F$10:SMI!$F$19,SMI!$G$10:SMI!$G$19),IF(I5=2,LOOKUP(K5,SMI!$F$10:$F$19,SMI!$H$10:$H$19),IF(I5=3,LOOKUP(K5,SMI!$F$10:SMI!$F$19,SMI!$I$10:SMI!$I$19),if(i5=4,lookup(k5,smi!$f$10:smi!$f$19,SMI!$J$10:SMI!$J$19,if(i5=5,lookup(k5,smi!$f$10:$F$19,smi!$k$10:smi!$k$19,if(i5=6,lookup(k5,smi!$f$10:smi!$F$19,smi!$l$10:smi!$L$19)))))))))))*C5`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the same formula after formatting:

```
=   IF( K5>10,
        G5+SMI!$G$25,
        IF( I5=1,
            LOOKUP( K5,
                    SMI!$F$10:SMI!$F$19,
                    SMI!$G$10:SMI!$G$19
                  ),
            IF( I5=2,
                LOOKUP( K5,
                        SMI!$F$10:$F$19,
                        SMI!$H$10:$H$19
                      ),
                IF( I5=3,
                    LOOKUP( K5,
                            SMI!$F$10:SMI!$F$19,
                            SMI!$I$10:SMI!$I$19
                          ),
                    if( i5=4,
                        lookup( k5,
                                smi!$f$10:smi!$f$19,
                                SMI!$J$10:SMI!$J$19,
                                if( i5=5,
                                    lookup( k5,
                                            smi!$f$10:$F$19,
                                            smi!$k$10:smi!$k$19,
                                            if( i5=6,
                                                lookup( k5,
                                                        smi!$f$10:smi!$F$19,
                                                        smi!$l$10:smi!$L$19
                                                      )
                                              )
                                          )
                                  )
                              )
                      )
                  )
              )
          )
      )
)*C5
```